# Warning: Detected "engines": { "node": ">=16.0.0 <20.0.0" } in your `package.json` that will automatically upgrade when a new major Node.js Version

Tags: reactjs, deployment, version, vercel, n

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYtGS.png)**"Warning: Detected "engines": { "node": ">=16.0.0 <20.0.0" } in your `package.json` that will automatically upgrade when a new major Node.js Version is released. Learn More: [http://vercel.link/node-version"](http://vercel.link/node-version%22)**

I cannot deploy my portfolio project, It's showing this version issues. How Can I fix this?
I tried multiple time, It says something like vercel is now allowing to build Node 16 versions and My project has Node 16.0.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.